# access each value of each hash inside an array

Tags: arrays, ruby, hash

I'm learning Ruby and I would like to know how to pick each `:values` I have stored in all the hashes inside an array at once. The data structure looks like this (with more hashes):

```
[ { :label => "Grid Singularity ", :values => [44, 1] }, 
  { :label => "iamsmart ", :values => [44, 1] } ]
```

If I do:

```
data_hash[0][:values] #=> [44, 1]
```

I can get the values of the first hash, but, how can I select each :values array at once? My goal is to be able to do the same operation with each :values without having to select them one by one (it's a very long list!)

Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: Your `data_hash` is actually an array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `map` to get a new array just taking the value of each `values` keys from the main hash, like:

```
hash = [
  {:label=>"Grid Singularity ", :values=>[44, 1]}, 
  {:label=>"iamsmart ",         :values=>[44, 1]}
]

p hash.map { |el| el[:values] }
# => [[44, 1], [44, 1]]
```